# Extracting tables from similarly structured PDF files using Camelot sometimes throws 'ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence'

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.11, python-camelot

I am using python 3.11 to extract tables from several (chemical analysis) PDF files that are all structured the same: at the top, there is some general information like date and sample number, then the rest is the actual measurements. I have a code that worked well for more than a hundred files except for 2.
When I run it, it returns `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`. More specifically from `xmin = min([t.x0 for direction in t_bbox for t in t_bbox[direction]])`

The specific line is:
`data = camelot.read_pdf(filename,pages='all', flavor='stream', strip_text='\n', table_areas=['350,850,580,30']), columns=['420,490']`.
If I remove `table_areas` and `columns` arguments, the function works but it doesn't detect the whole page, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTqQw.png) is the plot I get from running `camelot.plot(data[0], kind='contour').show()`. As you can see, it doesn't detect the whole page (nor the relevant data I want which is the two right-most columns). For reference, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXWm4.png) is how the plot should have looked (from a similar file) with `table_areas` and `columns` arguments.

As I said, every PDF file is structured similarly and I couldn't find any difference between the working files and the  2 files that cause the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tried extracting the data from the PDF file, and I expected to receive the data as a DataFrame containing the two right-most columns. This resulted in the error I mentioned earlier. Attempting to let Camelot auto-detect the table was unsuccessful.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004215/python-camelot-extracting-empty-tables Did you try using `table_regions` instead of `table_areas`?

Unresolved github issue: https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/263

Comment: When I use `table_regions` (without `columns` argument) I receive the following error: `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` from this line: `average_textline_height = sum_textline_height / float(len(textlines))`.

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87, do you have any insights? So far the only "solution" I found is handling the exception and printing a message that manual work is required.